# Azure WebApps - cannot load ServiceRuntime after upgrade to Azure 2.6

Tags: azure-web-app-service

After upgrading to Azure 2.6 (from 2.5) and publishing web into Azure Web Apps, the web fails to start with exception below. It seems Azure 2.6 is not yet available at Web Apps. Anyone experiences this?

`Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime, Version=2.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: Did you get this in runtime or during the publishing process?

Comment: Getting it in runtime

Comment: take a loot at the output windows while you publish the app. Maybe there are some info about the redirect you'll need to do. I faced the same problem using Windows.Azure.Storage: https://gist.github.com/thdotnet/b389ad252552368f5171

Answer (score 0):

Try add the reference manually from the SDK directory and create a binding redirects.

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure.NET SDK\v2.6\ref\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll

```
 <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WindowsAzureTelemetryEvents" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.0.0" newVersion="2.6.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WindowsAzureEventSource" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.0.0" newVersion="2.6.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="msshrtmi" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.0.0" newVersion="2.6.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.0.0" newVersion="2.6.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Tried that, but then it failed on dependent assembly `msshrtmi.dll`. It exists in GAC but I don't like the idea of deploying Azure 2.6 by myself. I just wonder if they didn't upgrade or what? With 2.5 it worked. Now I'm rather going to remove the dependencies on ServiceRuntime - they come from some shared lib that tests `RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable`

Comment: I faced the same problem using Windows.Azure.Storage package =/